# Query on scala Collections

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Both tuples and list are accepting the different type values as attached in snippet, then what is the main difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scala is a typed language. You want your program to know as much as possible about the shape of the data it is working with.

`List[Any]` is not a very useful type. It does not tell you that there are three elements in there, and what their respective types are.

`(Int, Double, String)` tells you much more.

Lists are for collections of elements of all the same type (but unknown number).

Tuples are for the combination of a fixed number of elements (that can each have their own type).

Tuples can also be seen as ad-hoc versions of case classes (which you have to define first, but then give you named fields, and methods and all that):

```
val myData = FooDataRecord(id = 1, amount = 1.1, name = "a")
```